# Probability of hitting a target exactly $3$ times

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Let's say we are throwing a ball until we hit a target exactly $3$ times. Hits are indipedent and the probability of hitting a target is $p=0.25$.
What's the probabability of that we need exactly 20 trials to hit the target exactly $3$ times?

My teacher gave this hint: "What is happening in the first 19 tries". What i have thought taking into account this hint is calculating the binomial probability $b(19, 0.25)$: $$P(X = 2) = \binom {19}{2}(0.25)^2(0.75)^{17} = 0.08$$.

However, i also thought using negative binomial probability $Nb(3, 0.25)$: $$P(X = 20) = \binom {20-1}{3-1}(0.25)^3(0.75)^{17} = 0.02$$

What is correct? I guess the first one is and i also guess i have not fully comprehend Negative binom distribution.

Comment: This is not clear.  Is the first question assuming that the $20^{th}$ trial is a hit?  That seems very unclear to me.  Nor do I understand what "average probability" is.

Comment: The issue may be whether you stop after 20 attempts (which happened to have three hits), or stop immediately after the third hit (which happened to be the 20th attempt)

Comment: @lulu The 20th trial is a hit(the third hit) and that's why we stop making other hits after this.

Comment: @Henry The second one.

Comment: Your teacher's hint would be helpful if the 20th try resulted in the 3rd hit ... but that is *not* what "the probability to hit exactly 3 times the target after 20 tries" suggests to me! Seems like a lousy hint. Did your teacher come up with this question? If so, and if your teacher meant to say that the 2oth try should be the third hit, then your teacher needs to phrase that question a lot more carefully!

Comment: I think the question is posed very poorly.  Multiple interpretations make sense.  You could be asking "given that I am going to try $20$ times no matter what, what is the probability that I hit the target exactly $3$ times?"  or "given that I intend to keep on trying until I get my third hit, what is the probability that I stop on trial $20$?" or "given that I tried $20$ times and got a hit on my last trial, what is the probability that I hit exactly $3$ times in total?"  These are different questions.

Comment: @Bram28 Maybe you are right and i didn't stated/translated it correctly.

Comment: @lulu I made an edit. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Yes, that is much clearer.  The probability that the third hit occurs on the $20^{th}$ trial is $p\times \binom {19}2\times p^2\times (1-p)^{17}=0.020084342$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\binom {19}{2}(0.25)^2(0.75)^{17} = 0.08$ is the conditional probability, given that the 20th attempt was a hit, that it was the third hit
- $\binom {20-1}{3-1}(0.25)^3(0.75)^{17} = 0.02$ is the overall probability that the 20th attempt was the third hit

It looks to me as if the question is asking for the second of these, which you can either state directly from the negative binomial, or by multiplying the first (ordinary binomial) by the probability that the 20th attempt was a hit, i.e. multiply the first probability by $0.25$

Comment: So, I guess that the first one is the correct answer for the problem.

Comment: @ΚωνσταντίνοςΚορναράκης You saw the original question, presumably in Greek, so may know better.  But from your translation, I would go for $0.02$ as the answer to "What's the probability that we need exactly 20 trials to hit the target exactly 3 times?"  My answer (based on yours) shows the two ways of calculating it

Comment: Maybe... I will examine the problem again but i am quite sure that the first one is correct. Otherwise, why would he give that hint which clearly (clearly for me at least) indicates the use of binomial distribution?